# Consulta sql para dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo una duda y es que estoy realizando una consulta sql server para llenar un `dropdownlist`  en vb.Net.

La cuestión es que en la consulta no puedo repetir los nombres que aparecen y tampoco debo mostrar los campos vacíos o null.

El problema para mi radica en que algunos datos tienen el mismo nombre en la base de datos pero con diferente ID, es decir si uso un `select disctinct` igual me va a mostrar el mismo nombre porque poseen diferente ID.

Esta es una parte de los datos que tengo en la base de datos, se ve el id y el nombre pero como digo, un campo tiene diferente id pero igual nombre y solo necesito mostrar uno de ellos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la duda de como realizar esa consulta bajo esos parámetros.

Comment: Que lenguaje utilizas, VB?. Indica también el **código**, es fundamental para poder responder a tu pregunta. Y por favor... redactar bien las preguntas, tomarse su tiempo, nada de prisas.

Comment: Ya modifique un poco la pregunta, estoy usando VB
Te agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Deja de intentar hacer maromas con el código y ve a corregir tus datos para eliminar duplicados y luego pon un UNIQUE CONSTRAINT en tu columna del nombre.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @LuisCazares, tu problema no está en el "distinct", sino en la inconsistencia de los datos de tu tabla (que además es una tabla maestra). Plantéate esto: entre `179 | Equitorial Trust Bank` y `105 | Equitorial Trust Bank`, cual elegirías para mostrar en el `dropdownlist`?.

Comment: tiene razon @RafaelAcosta tu base de datos es inconsistente. creo que debes de mejorar tus datos y una vez echo eso, el Disctinct te podria servir.

Comment: No puedo arreglar los datos, si lo pudiera obviamente los corregiría pero no tengo acceso a eso igual creo que ya lo soluciones, Gracias de todos modos

Answer (score -2):

Hola con la info que proporcionas parece un problema para usar `Group BY`

```
SELECT ID, FROM NAMEOFTABLE
GROUP BY NAME;
```

Si no podrias subir un ejemplo de que respuesta quisieras ver despues de la consulta y te ayudo a armar la consulta.

Saludos.